# Gitlab CI/CD one job depending on 2 other jobs

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I cannot find a way how to make one job (In my case `release_job`) depend on 2 other jobs (`build` and `prepare_job`).

My CI/CD pipeline:

```
# List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - release




# The below is a template for a CI/CD pipeline for ESP-IDF projects.
# It will build the project and generate a merged binary. After that, it will create a zip file with all the binaries
# and upload it as an artifact. Artifacts can then be accessed via other Jobs in the pipeline to manipulate them.
esp_idf_generate_build_files:
  image: espressif/idf:v5.0.4
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: normal
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # Run this job when a tag is created
  before_script:
    - idf.py build
  script:
    - mkdir binaries;
    - mkdir full_binary;
    - cd build; 
    - echo ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - esptool.py --chip esp32 merge_bin -o merged_fw.bin --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 40m --flash_size keep 0x1000 bootloader/bootloader.bin 0x10000 ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.bin 0x8000 partition_table/partition-table.bin 0xd000 ota_data_initial.bin 0xf000 phy_init_data.bin
    - cd ..
    - cp build/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}.bin
    #- cp build/bootloader/bootloader.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_bootloader.bin
    #- cp build/ota_data_initial.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_ota_data_initial.bin
    #- cp build/phy_init_data.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_phy_init_data.bin
    #- cp build/partition_table/partition-table.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_partition-table.bin
    - cp build/merged_fw.bin binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_full.bin

    - cd binaries
    - zip ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_binaries.zip *.bin # zip all .bin files
    - ls -la
    - cd ..
  after_script:
    - ls -l
    - cd full_binary
    - ls -l
    - touch JOB_ID.txt
    - echo GE_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID >> JOB_ID.txt
    - cat JOB_ID.txt
    - ls -l
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_binaries.zip
    reports:
      # To ensure we've access to this file in the next stage
      dotenv: full_binary/JOB_ID.txt





prepare_job:
  stage: prepare
  image: alpine:latest
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'
  script:
    - apk add curl jq
    - 'curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_API_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/changelog?version=$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | jq -r .notes > release_notes.md'
    - cat release_notes.md
  after_script:
    - touch JOB_ID.txt
    - echo GE_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID >> JOB_ID.txt
    - cat JOB_ID.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release_notes.md
    reports:
      # To ensure we've access to this file in the next stage
      dotenv: JOB_ID.txt




release_job:
    stage: release
    image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
    needs:
      - job: esp_idf_generate_build_files
        artifacts: true
      - job: prepare_job
        artifacts: true
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # Run this job when a tag is created
    script:
      - echo "running release_job"
      - echo $CI_PROJECT_URL
    release: # See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release for available properties
      name: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      description: release_notes.md
      tag_name: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      ref: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
      assets:
        links:
          - name: '${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_binaries'
            url: '$CI_PROJECT_URL/-/jobs/${GE_JOB_ID}/artifacts/file/binaries/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_TAG}_binaries.zip'
          - name: 'Changelog'
            url: '$CI_PROJECT_URL/-/jobs/${GE_JOB_ID}/artifacts/file/release_notes.md'
```

As you can see I have tried to extend `needs` in release_job:

```
    needs:
      - job: esp_idf_generate_build_files
        artifacts: true
      - job: prepare_job
        artifacts: true
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
'release_job' job needs 'prepare_job' job, but 'prepare_job' is not in any previous stage
```

I need my `release job` to retrieve artifacts from both previous jobs that is why I am trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prepare_job:    
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'

release_job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # Run this job when a tag is created
```

Your `prepare_job` has a different set of (more restrictive) rules from your `release_job`. It failed because you tried it with a tag which had matched the rules set for the `release_job`, but not the rules for the `prepare_job`.

As you haven't declared the dependency as `optional`, that's an immediate pipeline failure.

Comment: Well spotted. I have additionally spotted that both of my jobs that ```release job``` depends on append to GE_JOB_ID.

How can my ```release_job``` know which artifact belongs to which job?

Comment: > How can my release_job know which artifact belongs to which job?

It can't. You have to help yourself with unique subfolders or file names to identify the origin of artifacts.